# Oracle importar dmp (impdp) da fallos ORA-39006, ORA-39065, ORA-01001, ORA-06512, ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Estoy importando un volcado de Oracle (dmp) y me da una serie de errores que no sé por dónde abordarlos. Está en una máquina Linux.

La sentencia para importar es de este tipo:

`impdp usu/pass@instanciaBD directory=bfile_dir schemas=miEsquema dumpfile=midmp.dmp logfile=imp_midmp.log`.

El directorio lo he definido con `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY bfile_dir as '/home/oracle/midir';`

Los errores que me dan son:

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39006: error interno
ORA-39065: excepcion inesperada del proceso maestro en DISPATCH
ORA-01001: cursor no valido
ORA-06512: en "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_UTIL", linea 3588
ORA-06512: en "SYS.KUPM$MCP", linea 2628

ORA-39097: El trabajo de pump de datos ha encontrado un error inesperado -1001
```

Lo curioso es que si le indico en la sentencia para importar un "FULL=y", parece no dar error, pero tampoco hace nada (el esquema de base de datos se queda igual de vacío):

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
UDI-00010: multiple job modes requested, full and schemas.
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo indica que hay objetos inválidos en tu BD, posiblemente después de un parche o algo así.

Revisa con

```
SET LINES 200
COL OBJECT_NAME FOR A35
COL OBJECT_TYPE FOR A25
COL Owner FOR A25
Select owner,object_name,object_type,status,created,LAST_DDL_TIME from dba_objects where status='INVALID' and owner='SYS' order by object_name;
```

Prueba iniciar sesión con sys y correr esto: `exec dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets;`

Prueba también recompilando objetos inválidos con estos scripts utilitarios que vienen con la instalación

```
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/catmet2.sql
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Ahí prueba de nuevo `Select owner,object_name,object_type,status,created,LAST_DDL_TIME from dba_objects where status='INVALID' and owner='SYS' order by object_name;` y debería dar cero filas; podrás intentar impdp de nuevo

Comment: Lo que me has indicado parece servir @Alfabravo. Aunque no ha eliminado todos los objetos inválidos ya no muestra los errores (ahora tengo que resolver nuevos problemas). Gracias

Comment: Puedes editar  y añadir los errores adicionales, o crear una nueva pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data_pump_dir is corrupted somehow

```
bash-4.2$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> drop directory data_pump_dir;
SQL> exit;
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Recuerda que el idioma del sitio es el español. Traduce tu respuesta.